# Glut functions. Use a glut functions leads to a drop of a program

Tags: c#, opengl, frameworks, tao-framework

I use Tao Framework for lerning openGL. I included all libraries what that need, including Tao.FreeGlut.dll. At a execution stage program at the point of use glut function terminates. Why this is so? errors at compile time does not occur, the program just closes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tao.DevIl;
using Tao.OpenGl;
using Tao.FreeGlut;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);           
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();             

        Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT.Width / (float)AnT.Height, 0.1, 200);

        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);          
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();              


        Draw();
    }
    public void Draw() {
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        float[] color = new float[4] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
        float[] shininess = new float[1] { 30 };
        Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, color); 
        Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, color);
        Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SHININESS, shininess);
        //----------------------------
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(0, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(45, 1, 1, 0);

        Glut.glutSolidTeapot(1);  // <- exit
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glFlush();
        AnT.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: You never initialized GLUT from what I can tell. I've no idea how that works in C#, but in the C interface to GLUT you have to call `glutInit (...)` using the `argc` and `argv` variables you get from your `main (...)` function. I imagine there's something similar in C#, or it might just be a void function.

Comment: Thank you for help, Andon M. Coleman

Comment: I have just stated learning openGL with GLUT and this book came in handy, it saved me in my numerous times of need. I would recommend that you take a look at this. <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321773039/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0321773039&linkCode=as2&tag=mulrothub-20&linkId=TAPNUQWWBSMBUNB4">OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Version 4.3 (8th Edition)</a><img src="http://ir-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=mulrothub-20&l=as2&o=1&a=0321773039" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin

Answer (score 1):

Andon M. Coleman, thanks. Glut library must be initialized before using

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @gnat - The answer in question had been posted as a comment, so this was the correct action to take.